# Checking the linearity assumption in multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, assumptions, linearity

If I wanted to check the mentioned assumption, it is quite easy for only 1 predictor, but what if I have several?
I read online that I can plot the residuals vs predicted and see there is no pattern, but I also read that you can plot k scatterplots for k predictors individually (like in simple regression but k times)

My question is, why is that correct? Isn't the relationship of all predictors together different from the relationship of each predictor with y? Isn't doing this check assumed independence between the predictors?

Comment: [Linearity assumption of linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435411/linearity-assumption-of-linear-regression)

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/595551/ramsey-reset-test/595624#595624